# "Android studio is currently running" error

Tags: android, installation

I have just downloaded the new version of Android Studio. When I run the setup file, it gives me an error:

```
Android studio is currently running. Please exit the application and press OK to continue with the installation
```

But I don't have Android studio opened.

Comment: did you check the processes in the task manager (or other processes manager depending on your OS)?

Comment: I dont know what I should search for in task manager. at least I'm pretty sure it is not open in my desktop, casue I have just turned on my PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer looks for a running process named either studio or studio64 (depending of course on your system architecture). Find and kill this process in order to continue.

Comment: I identified the process from the AS icon.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click `Android Studio Setup File` and select `Run as administrator`

Answer (score 1):

Are you having some other IDE running? Stop that before installation. Helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open your task manager and find this ("adb") in the list then close it

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, even with admin rights...

finally i put the program out of the windows download folder to the desktop and closed some other programs (word) which should have actually nothing to do with android studio. Also started with admin rights and voilá - installation is running now :)

Answer (score 0):

An edge case, but if you are running Simplicity Studio (an Eclipse-based IDE from Silicon Labs) you'll have to close it. It is shown in process explorer as 'studio' and seems to confuse the Android Studio installer.

Answer (score 0):

It's so late..but I had same problem and I solved this just moments ago.
[Ctrl+shift+esc] and you can open up "Task manager" (I'm korean, so i don't know Eng_name. sry) and you can see android studio in background process and you should right click and finish it then it's solved

Answer (score 0):

you should go to task manager and find all services which is related to android studio. just end it and you should also need to close the clone of ADB then you can install the new version.

Note : make sure when you have install the version you should open with the admin permission or with the user that have all rights..

Answer (score 0):

**i had same problem** . but i found a solution .
this is Steps works for me

**Step 1** : Go to task manager

**Step 2** : Search android file

**Step 3** : click right on android file

**step 4** : Select end task

Open again Andorid Studio

Successfully Open Thank you

Answer (score 0):

kill the scheme and open your task manager and find this ("adb") in the list then close it